# how to pass a Dictionary value from view to template in django application

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, dictionary

I am just trying to learn a django project. I already did the creation of project and inside project myapp using django command.
In the directory **/myproject/myapp$** I have views.py file. Another directory **/myproject/myapp/templates$** I have hello.html file. I want send a Dictionary value from views.py file to hello.html file using render function. But I am getting some error called

```
**Internal Server Error: /hello/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/joy/pythonWork/myproject/myapp/views.py", line 8, in hello
    name     : 'xyz',
NameError: global name 'name' is not defined**
```

I donot have any idea, how to solve this problem.Someone please help me.
My files are listed bellow:

/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def hello(request):
   personalDetails = {
       name     : 'xyz',
       phoneno  : '722924374'
   }
   return render(request, "hello.html", {personalDetails})
```

/hello.html

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Hello</h1>{{personalDetails}}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a dictionary. Dictionary keys should be strings.

```
def hello(request):
   personal_details = {
       'name': 'xyz',
       'phoneno': '7022924374',
   }
   return render(request, 'hello.html', {'personal_details': personal_details})
```

Comment: return render(request, "hello.html", {"personal_details": personal_details})   
                                                                                    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Answer (score 0):

You should use `render` like this.

```
return render(request, "hello.html", {"personalDetails": personalDetails})
```

Comment: In Browser: NameError at /hello/ global name 'name' is not defined Request Method: GET ....

Comment: Dis you fix `{{personalDetails}}` to `{{personalDeatils.name}}`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this change

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def hello(request):
   personalDetails = {
       name     : 'xyz',
       phoneno  : '722924374'
   }
   return render(request, "hello.html", **personalDetails)
```

and in your html

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Hello</h1>{{name}}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In Browser: NameError at /hello/
global name 'name' is not defined
Request Method: GET

Comment: try changing as above or if you are passing a dict in template then use dict lookup filter for fetching value from dict

Answer (score -1):

```
def hello(request):
   personalDetails = {
       name     : 'xyz',
       phoneno  : '7022924374'
   }
   return render(request, "hello.html", {"personalDetails":personalDetails})
```

And in template:

```
<html>
<body>
{% for item in personalDetails %}
   <h1>Hello</h1>{{item.name}}
{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In Browser: NameError at /hello/ global name 'name' is not defined Request Method: GET ....

Comment: key in python dictionary must be a string.